# Google Cloud SQL Exception

Tags: mysql, sql, database, cloud

I am trying to do a SQL database in Google Cloud SQL and with  a Java project make many queries to the database, but I have this answer:
Buckets:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Required parameter project must be specified.
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException.translateAndThrow(StorageException.java:73)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.listBuckets(StorageImpl.java:288)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.list(StorageImpl.java:257)
at package1.Auth.authExplicit(Auth.java:46)
at package1.Main.main(Main.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Required parameter project must be specified
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String instanceConnectionName="";
    String databaseName="prueba";
    String username="root";
    String password="root";
    String sql="SELECT * FROM alumnos";
    String jsonPath="/Users/franciscomanuelpozodelmoral/Downloads/Team5-c4e75c7cb498.json";

    Auth.authExplicit(jsonPath);

    try {       
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String jdbcURL=String.format("jdbc:mysql://google/%s?cloudSqlInstance=%s&" + 
        "socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory",databaseName,instanceConnectionName);

        Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, username, password);

        Statement statement=connection.createStatement();   
        ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("DNI") + rs.getString("Nombre") + rs.getString("Apellidos") + rs.getInt("Telefono")+rs.getInt("Curso"));
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Auth {

    static void authImplicit() {
        // If you don't specify credentials when constructing the client, the client library will
        // look for credentials via the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.

        //Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
        Storage storage=StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

        System.out.println("Buckets:");
        Page<Bucket> buckets = storage.list();
        for (Bucket bucket : buckets.iterateAll()) {
            System.out.println(bucket.toString());
        }
    }

    static void authExplicit(String jsonPath) throws IOException {
        // You can specify a credential file by providing a path to GoogleCredentials.
        // Otherwise credentials are read from the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(jsonPath))
            .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
        Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();

        System.out.println("Buckets:");
        Page<Bucket> buckets = storage.list();
        // for (Bucket bucket : buckets.iterateAll()) {
        //   System.out.println(bucket.toString());
        //  }
    }
}
```

Can you help me? Thanks (The instanceConnectionName is group5...)

Comment: Please describe the flow of your code as well as where and why you think it is failing. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried authenticate with the .json file. I get this .json file from google, that contains RSA keys. I connect with database and I try execute the query SQL, but I get this exception.